# PeopleSoft Subquery not picking up correct leave plans

Tags: peoplesoft

I'm attempting to build a report in PeopleSoft's Query Manager that has future and current employees on it. I want to be able to find the employees who do not have leave plans, specifically 50 and 52. I thought I was on the right track with the following BUT after auditing my report it is bringing in people who HAVE 50 and 52. I think it has to do with the subquery (SQL below).

Here are some pictures of query manager:

[image: Top Level]

[image: Subquery]

```
SELECT DISTINCT B.COMPANY, A.EMPLID, A.NAME, B.FULL_PART_TIME, B.REG_TEMP, C.DESCR, D.PLAN_TYPE, (CASE WHEN  B.REG_TEMP = 'T' THEN '' WHEN  C.DESCR = 'Intern' THEN '' WHEN  C.DESCR = 'PenFed Intern' THEN '' ELSE 'Check records/give Leave' END), CONVERT(CHAR(10),SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR,GETDATE(),121), 1, 10),121)), (CONVERT(CHAR(10),SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR,GETDATE(),121), 1, 10),121)), (CONVERT(CHAR(10),SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR,GETDATE(),121), 1, 10),121)) 
FROM (PS_PERSONAL_DATA A LEFT OUTER JOIN  (PS_LEAVE_PLAN D INNER JOIN PS_EMPLMT_SRCH_QRY D1 ON (D.EMPLID = D1.EMPLID AND D.EMPL_RCD = D1.EMPL_RCD AND  D1.OPRID = 'XXXXXXXX' )) ON  A.EMPLID = D.EMPLID ), PS_PFC_JOB_VW B, PS_JOBCODE_TBL C, PS_SET_CNTRL_REC C2 
WHERE ( C.JOBCODE = B.JOBCODE 
AND C2.SETCNTRLVALUE = B.BUSINESS_UNIT 
AND C2.RECNAME = 'JOBCODE_TBL' 
AND C2.SETID = C.SETID 
AND ( A.EMPLID = B.EMPLID 
 AND ( B.EFFDT = 
    (SELECT MAX(B_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_PFC_JOB_VW B_ED 
    WHERE B.EMPLID = B_ED.EMPLID 
      AND B.EMPL_RCD = B_ED.EMPL_RCD 
      AND B_ED.EFFDT <= SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR,GETDATE(),121), 1, 10)) 
AND B.EFFSEQ = 
    (SELECT MAX(B_ES.EFFSEQ) FROM PS_PFC_JOB_VW B_ES 
    WHERE B.EMPLID = B_ES.EMPLID 
      AND B.EMPL_RCD = B_ES.EMPL_RCD 
      AND B.EFFDT = B_ES.EFFDT) 
 OR ( B.EFFDT = 
    (SELECT MIN(B_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_PFC_JOB_VW B_ED 
    WHERE B.EMPLID = B_ED.EMPLID 
      AND B.EMPL_RCD = B_ED.EMPL_RCD 
      AND B_ED.EFFDT >= SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR,GETDATE(),121), 1, 10)) 
AND B.EFFSEQ = 
    (SELECT MAX(B_ES.EFFSEQ) FROM PS_PFC_JOB_VW B_ES 
    WHERE B.EMPLID = B_ES.EMPLID 
      AND B.EMPL_RCD = B_ES.EMPL_RCD 
      AND B.EFFDT = B_ES.EFFDT) 
 AND B.ACTION IN ('HIR','REH','REI'))) 
 AND B.EMPL_STATUS IN ('A','L','P') 
 AND B.PER_ORG = 'EMP' 
 AND C.EFFDT = 
    (SELECT MAX(C_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_JOBCODE_TBL C_ED 
    WHERE C.SETID = C_ED.SETID 
      AND C.JOBCODE = C_ED.JOBCODE 
      AND C_ED.EFFDT <= B.EFFDT) 
 AND A.EMPLID NOT IN (SELECT E.EMPLID 
FROM PS_LEAVE_PLAN E, PS_EMPLMT_SRCH_QRY E1 
WHERE E.EMPLID = E1.EMPLID 
AND E.EMPL_RCD = E1.EMPL_RCD 
AND E1.OPRID = 'XXXXXXXX' 
AND ( E.EFFDT = 
    (SELECT MAX(E_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_LEAVE_PLAN E_ED 
    WHERE E.EMPLID = E_ED.EMPLID 
      AND E.EMPL_RCD = E_ED.EMPL_RCD 
      AND E.PLAN_TYPE = E_ED.PLAN_TYPE 
      AND E.BENEFIT_NBR = E_ED.BENEFIT_NBR 
      AND E_ED.EFFDT <= SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR,GETDATE(),121), 1, 10)) 
 AND ( E.PLAN_TYPE = '50' 
 OR E.PLAN_TYPE = '52') )) ))
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried without the EFFDT criteria in the subquery?

Comment: Yes. There's no difference.

Comment: Try running the subquery by itself and see if it returns emplids.