# PeopleSoft Query Manager - can reporting not pick up future leave plans?

Tags: peoplesoft

This question is a result of this [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55639168/peoplesoft-subquery-not-picking-up-correct-leave-plans). Basically I'm trying to find out if future hires already have their leave plans in the system. I'm limited to PeopleSoft's in built Query Manager.

I'm aware that there are limitations in reporting with regard to seeing future hires job data records. My team built a view into that table so that I can run reports off of it.

I've been trying to build reports regarding future hires leave plans and I want to know if this is another issue with PeopleSoft - in other words, is this an issue we'd have to build another view in order to see future leave plans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is probably highly dependent on how your environment is setup and what kind of permissions your user has.

However, checking if you can see/if there are future leave plans in the system should be trivial:

```
SELECT * FROM PS_LEAVE_PLAN;
```

or via PSQuery in the records tab, select LEAVE_PLAN and select all fields.

Then check if you have EFFDT fields with future dates.

Comment: Yes, I agree and I did do something similar to that. The future dated leave plans did not show up on the report. 

So i was wondering if this was similar to how PeopleSoft treats future hires.